# How can I measure memory usage of java method

Tags: java, performance, jvm

sounds strange, but still.

Imagine I have a java method

```
boolean myMethod(Object param1, Object param2) { 
   // here can be some simple calculations. can be some services invokation
   // or calls to DB. doesn't matter
  return someValue;
}
```

How can I measure how much memory JVM uses to execute this method ? How much memory actually uses this method for its execution ?

Is there any tools or I maybe I can add some extra code to my method to be able to see used memory ?

I am using `JConsole` to monitor JVM, I also know that we can use `java.lang.Runtime` to see freeMemory, but actually I can't figure out how much memory my method uses with this tools.

Comment: You can use profiling tool like jProfiler .

Comment: The later JDKs include JVisualVM.  Its pretty good, successor to JConsole.  I use JVisualVM for overall profiling.  JProfiler is very good, not free.  I've also used Jamon.  http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/ - painful to get going but quite useful.

Comment: U can use terminal for this particular usage know na.

Comment: What counts as the memory used per method call. Are you asking for stack size, or heap usage.. or both?

Comment: @ChrisK for heap usage

Comment: @john in that case could you define which objects you are interested in measuring for that metric?  objects are allocated into a shared memory area, and so it is not clear how much memory an object contributes to a single method call.  Which is why tools like jprofiler do not report on this directly.  However there are tools that can link objects back to their roots, but double counting is a high risk.

Comment: @john perhaps describing what you are hoping to discover/solve will help.  one very useful metric is allocation rate, which tells us which methods are responsible for creating the most instances of each object.  That can be used to reduce object churn, and thus stress on the GC.  However it is not clear from your question what the underlying motive is.

Comment: Do not provide clarifications in comments.  Instead, edit your question so it is clearer. If you do that, your question might be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Measuring the true size of of each invocation of a method is not as simple as it sounds and the JVM does not support it.  The complexity comes about a) because the JVM was designed to hide this low level detail and b) the JVM may have more than one variation of the same method in flight at any point of time, which sounds nuts but it is also true.  Some times the method will have been inlined, or optimised more heavily or even recompiled in a special way to support hot swapping of the method while it is running (!) which can radically change its runtime size.

**Measuring the amount of heap used by a method call**

Given that method invocations do not use the heap, it is tempting to say 0 bytes.  However one may want to know the size of any new object that was allocated by a method call.  This can be answered, however objects are shared across method calls and threads.  So one has to be very clear about what they want to measure, and take care to not count it twice.  There are libraries that will give the size of an Object in Java, they usually work either by reflection and a heuristic or they wrap sun.misc.Unsafe to inspect pointers to the object and its data.  For example http://code.google.com/p/javabi-sizeof/.

**Measuring the allocation rate of a method**

YourKit has an excellent tool described [here](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/allocations.jsp) for tracking every object allocation at its source point and reporting back their total size and rates.  Very useful for finding out who is causing GC churn.

**Measuring the amount of stack used per method call**

The JVM does not publish this information, and as mentioned before it will vary depending on the optimizations that are currently active and which runtime compiler is being used.

The alternative is to use a heuristic.  Something like counting up how many variables are used within the method and multiply the count by 4 to give an answer in bytes (which assumes that every variable is 4 bytes in size, ie an int).  Obviously this heuristic is flawed and could be improved, but it is simple enough to give a quick and fairly representative answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the following in the past, and I found it to be useful:

http://www.javamex.com/classmexer/