# Measure the function-level memory usage in Scala in my Application Code during runtime

Tags: scala, memory-profiling

First of all, this is not an "off-line" profiling task!

I am working on some `SCala` codebase, and currently what I am trying to do is, if a function `foo` consumes too many memory (let's say over 10G), kill this function and return a default value.

So it should look like:

```
monitor{
  foo()   <--- if foo has used over 10G memory, just cut it off
}
catch {
  case MemoryUsageError => default_value
}
```

Note that currently `foo` is running in the same process with my `main` function.

Is it possible to do so? I quickly googled such materials and only find a way to show the current memory usage of a `SCala` application; it is not as fine-grained as what I am looking for.

Am I clear on this? Could anyone shed some lights here? Thanks a lot!

========================================================================

Note that what I am looking for is an "**online**" method! It is not like **off-line** profiling. My application ifself should determine the memory usage of `foo` function, and if it goes too high, just cut it off.

Comment: The most probable case you have only one "heavy" object (or one group of objects). If all instances are about the same size then simple counter solves  the problem.
Another way is jvm instrumentation.

Comment: @Zernike， thank you for your information. Could you please elaborate on it a little bit more? I cannot get your point..

Comment: @computereasy what kind of memory are you considering: stack memory or heap memory? Are you trying to guard against stack overflow errors, or simply too much heap memory allocated via `new`?

Comment: @MikeAllen, the later one. The foo function is likely to allocate too many objects on the heap along the execution..

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, function `foo` could use all the memory, and halt the program. On the other hand, if `foo` takes too much time to finish, in my context, it is safe to return a default value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I measure memory usage of java method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055745/how-can-i-measure-memory-usage-of-java-method)

Comment: @OlivierBlanvillain. This is not a duplication. I have explain in the question. "Note that what I am looking for is an "online" method! It is not like off-line profiling. My application ifself should determine the memory usage of foo function, and if it goes too high, just cut it off.". Could you please disable the "duplication" sign?

Comment: @computereasy Scala runs on the JVM. You are not gonna get a better (Scala specific) answer to what is on the question I've linked.

Comment: @OlivierBlanvillain you don't understand my point at all

Answer (score 0):

### Is it possible?

In general jvm doesn't track creator of objects allocated on heap and place of creation. This is very costly and doesn't matter for GC.

### How to live with it

#### Termination

1. Self-controlled program. If you want terminate some continuous computation then computation shouldn't be continuous. What you need is check points where condition could be validated. For example, every start of iteration in a loop or at the beginning of every recursive call. Obviously computation could consist of several different stages instead of simple loop but approach is the same.
2. Separation of computation and control. For example, execute function as `Future` with predetermined `Thread` and interrupt it if needed or using `ForkJoinTask` and `cancel()` method.

#### Measurement

1. Usually only one or couple of classes fulfill most of the memory. If instances are about the same size then memory control could be implemented with counter of objects. Classes of 'heavy' objects could be find by inspection of algorithm or using jvisualvm. Increase counter during instance creation. Decrement is harder. Update counter when references are released (count instances that couldn't be removed by GC) or use PhantomReference (count all instances existed in VM). But don't use `finalize()`!
2. Second method is java instrumentation package. It allows to measure objects size (probably there are methods determining consumption of all objects of certain class). Also you could try [measuring available memory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory--). The flaw is you measure objects of not certain function but all of them.
3. For time control write down timestamp at the beginning of computation and measure duration at every check point.